# how to get length of an ajax object

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to get the length of the 'obj' object so that I can do a for-loop with it, here is my code:

```
var oRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
var sURL = "/Users/files/Documents/time.json";
oRequest.open("GET",sURL,false);
oRequest.send();
var txt = oRequest.responseText;
var obj = eval ("(" + txt + ")");
```

My goal is that I would like to output everything in this time.json file to the screen.

Here is what my json file looks like:

```
{
"employees": [
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
]
}
```

Comment: obj.employees.length is what you want

Comment: have your tried employees.length?

Comment: `var obj = eval ("(" + txt + ")");`? We aren't in the dark ages any more. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: try this... var objt = {
"employees": [
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
]
}
console.log(objt.employees.length);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have to get a length in order to do a for loop on an object, based on your object structure you can get data with the following loop:

```
for(var key in object) {
   var o = object[key];

   for(var i = 0; i < o.length; i++)  {
      var user = o[i];

      alert(user.firstName);
   }
}
```

Comment: Where are you not using the length?

Comment: But you use length in the for loop, which is what OP wanted

Answer (score 1):

The object you create does not have have a length. I assume you meant employees length and not the obj length

Like this:

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/k35L4/)

```
var txt = oRequest.responseText;
// eval("var obj = "+txt); // eval is not recommended but here is how
var obj = JSON.parse(txt); // this is better
var emp = obj?obj.employees:[]; // if we have a useful object, get the employees
window.onload=function() {
  var empDiv = document.getElementById("empDiv");
  for (var i=0;i<emp.length;i++) {
    empDiv.innerHTML+=emp[i].firstName + " "+ emp[i].lastName + '<br/>';
  }
}
```